# Setting default gVim font via `vimrc`, conditional on the operating system

Tags: vimrc, gvim, linux, font, default-settings

I can place the following code into my `_vimrc` file on *Windows 7/10* and the font will default to 'Consolas - size 11' when I launch gVim.

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Ubuntu Mono\ 15
  elseif has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Menlo\ Regular:h14
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif
```

If I place this same code into my *Ubuntu 18.04* `vimrc` file I don't get the expected 'Ubuntu Mono - size 15'. I just get the default font and size, as if my new `vimrc` code did nothing.

What do I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Linux machine with graphical interface here to test it, but I'd say the correct syntax for that line would be something like:

`set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 15`

Comment: @joão-a-toledo It's `set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 15`. Just tested on Ubuntu. Could you fix it?